# Using Parameters in Neo4j Relationship Queries

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm struggling to work around a small limitation of Neo4j in that I am unable to use a parameter in the Relationship section of a Cypher query.

Christophe Willemsen has already graciously assisted me in working my query to the following:

```
MATCH (n1:Point { name: {n1name} }),
      (n2:Point { name: {n2name} }),
      p = shortestPath((n1)-[r]->(n2))
WHERE type(r) = {relType}
RETURN p
```

Unfortunately as `r` is a Collection of relationships and not a single relationship, this fails with an error:

`scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship`

Removing the use of `shortestPath()` allows the query to run successfully but returns no results.

Essentially my graph is a massive collection of "paths" that link "points" together. It is currently structured as such:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/rholp

I need to be able to provide a starting point (`n1Name`), an ending point (`n2Name`), and a single path to travel along (`relType`). I need a list of nodes to come out of the query (all the ones along the path).

Have I structured my graph incorrectly / not optimally? I am open to advice on whether the overall structure is not optimal as well as advice on how best to structure the query!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you will pass as parameter for the relationship type ? multiple parameters like array('PATH1','PATH2') or a single name ?

Comment: A single name - `PATH_ONE`

Comment: Your error is not related to parameters. You should use `where` instead of `and`.

Comment: Apologies Dirk - that was a typo. Christophe corrected it in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Regarding your edit, the **nodes()** function returns you the nodes along the path :

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((n:Point { name:"Point5" })-[*]->(n2:Point { name:"Point8" }))
WHERE ALL (r IN rels(p) WHERE type(r)={relType})
RETURN nodes(p)
```

In the console link, it is returning nodes Points 5,6,7,8

---

I guess in your case that using a common relationship type name for connecting your **Point** nodes would be more efficient.

If having a Path1, Path2, .. is for knowing the distance between two points, you can easily know the distance by asking for the length of the path, like this query related to your console link :

```
MATCH (n:Point { name:"Point1" })
WITH n
MATCH (n2:Point { name:"Point4" })
WITH n, n2
MATCH p=shortestPath((n)-[]->(n2))
RETURN length(p)
```

If you need to return only paths having a defined relationship length, you can use it without the shortestPath by specifying a strict depth :

```
MATCH (n:Point { name:"Point1" })
WITH n
MATCH (n2:Point { name:"Point4" })
WITH n, n2
MATCH p=(n)-[*3..3]->(n2)
RETURN length(p)
LIMIT1
```

As you can see here, the need to specify the relationship is not mandatory, you can just omit it or add the :NEXT type if you have other relationship types in your graph

If you need to match on the type, for e.g. the path from point 5 to point 8 in your console link, and the path can only have a PATH_TWO relationship, then you can do this :

```
MATCH (n:Point { name:"Point5" })
WITH n
MATCH (n2:Point { name:"Point8" })
WITH n, n2
MATCH p=(n)-[r*]->(n2)
WHERE type(r[0])= 'PATH_TWO'
WITH p, length(p) AS l
ORDER BY l
RETURN p, l
LIMIT 1
```

If you really NEED to have the Path1, Path2 style, maybe a short explanation on the need could help us find the more appropriate query

Comment: Thanks, Christophe. What I need is all the nodes on the path from A to B - so from my console, if I used `Point1` as my start, `Point4` as my finish, and `PATH_ONE` as my path, I would need a return of `Point1, Point2, Point3, Point4` (or at the very least `Point2, Point3`).

I have edited my original post to more clearly explain the requirement of the query.

Comment: Hooo ok, you need to look at the nodes(p) function then, let me edit my answer

Comment: Edited ;-) Added an example with nodes

Comment: The top query works well in the console but just hangs on my Neo4j database.

Comment: `:schema` shows: `Indexes
  ON :Point(name) ONLINE`. The relationship type is the entire point of this exercise, I'm afraid! I could absolutely inject the string into Cypher in my calling script - but that would leave me open to injection attacks. Would need to do some serious sanity checking!

Comment: By jove I think you've cracked it! The latest edit works a charm.

Comment: also instead of `rels(p)` you can just use your original `r`

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH p=shortestpath((n1:Point{name:{n1name}})-[:relType *]->(n2:Point {name:{n2name}})) 
RETURN p
```